# Is Twitter consumer secret required for reverse authentication?

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm busy with implementing reverse authentication on iOS. I'm making it on the base of [this example](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample) and [twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth).

I'm trying to figure out whether the consumer secret is mandatory to perform STEP 1 from the docs (obtaining a special request token). The docs say:

> As an example, consider a request with the following values signed with the consumer key JP3PyvG67rXRsnayOJOcQ and consmer secret ydC2yUbFaScbSlykO0PmrMjXFeLraSi3Q2HfTOlGxQM.

Seems like the secret is needed. But then it lists the parameters for the request:

> oauth_consumer_key  JP3PyvG67rXRsnayOJOcQ

```
oauth_nonce 1B7D865D-9E15-4ADD-8165-EF90D7A7D3D2
oauth_signature_method  HMAC-SHA1
oauth_timestamp 1322697052
oauth_version   1.0
x_auth_mode reverse_auth
```

and there's no secret. and also no `oath_signature`. It then confirms my suspicion by the following:

> These parameters should result in a signature base string that looks like this:
>
> POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&

```
 oauth_consumer_key%3DJP3PyvG67rXRsnayOJOcQ%26
 oauth_nonce%3D1B7D865D-9E15-4ADD-8165-EF90D7A7D3D2%26
 oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26
 oauth_timestamp%3D1322697052%26
 oauth_version%3D1.0%26
 x_auth_mode%3Dreverse_auth
```

again, no secret and no `oath_signature` parameter. Then i look at the example app i have taken from the GitHub and see that it actually makes use of the secret. It makes some magic, mixes the secret with different strings, encrypts it and makes it into `oauth_signature` parameter which goes into the authorization header for its request. The complete authorisation header looks like this:

> OAuth oauth_timestamp="1405695110", oauth_nonce="0C38A128-42B1-41D1-B31D-EBEBE8971470", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_consumer_key="u97hVQZtAcRbLWHv5CkONbaJ8", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="iuaqaN1MvFHyKMa95LFWXCxUfDM%3D"

The only difference between this and Twitter doc's example is that here is `oauth_signature` parameter (made from the secret) present. And the example works all right. I tried removing the secret when making the signature and received an error from Twitter.

So I am confused. The docs don't clearly state that the secret is required whereas the example uses it as its important part. So is it mandatory? And if not can you please explain how do I build a request without the secret?

Comment: Yes consumer key and secret are needed. have you looked at cocoapod TWReverseAuth?

Comment: @hackerinheels thanks for your response. i'll take a look at that library